# What are application level classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader, terminology

I am a beginner in java, I just started reading about JVM internals. I was going through the hierarchy of class loaders. I found out that system class loader takes care of loading all the application level classes into the JVM. So I want to know what are the application level classes exactly?
Source : https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders

Comment: There is no formal definition of the term “application level classes”. The usual definition is exactly those given by the article. Application level classes are those loaded by the system class loader, also known as application class loader. Informally, these classes are *your* classes when you are developing a Java application.

Comment: Application level classes are the ones you write and depend on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, the application level classes are the classes that belong to the application - i.e., classes that aren't part of the platform, such as the JDK's classes.